# Deploy Maven Web Application with MySQL to Tomcat from Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans and trying to deploy a simple maven web application to a my local Tomcat server with MySQL using JNDI, but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'"

I also tried with 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', but I still got the same errror.

I read some pages on the internet that I need to import the mysql JAR, but as I already have it on my project (as a Maven Dependency) I don't get why it doesn't work.
Do I need to manually import the JAR to Tomcat? If so, is there a way to use the same that is in my maven dependency?

If that matters, I'm on Windows 10.

Sorry for english errors, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Build with Dependency option in Netbeans? After building it creates `YourProjectName.war` file inside `target` folder just open it with 7zip or Winrar application. And inside `WEB-INF` folder check whether `mysql-connector.jar` file was included or not.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this error when i started using the new classpath for mysql.

Have a look at my code it may help.

```
 public static final String CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
 public static final String SQLURI = "jdbc:mysql://";

 public MySQLDatabase(String host, String database, String username, String password) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class.forName(CLASSNAME).newInstance();
        Host = host;
        Database = database;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        String uri = SQLURI;

        uri = uri + Host + "/" + Database;

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(uri, Username, Password);

        System.out.Println("log in success")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I'm using JNDI I don't have a connection code, only a xml:
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
              username="root" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>